# Typescript: string | string[] to string[]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a value of type `string | string[]`.
I want to convert into into the type `string[]`.
My current solution is:

```
const role: string | string[] = 'admin';
const roles: string[] = Array.isArray(role) ? role : [role];
```

Maybe typescript has a built-in way to do so? Or you know a more clean solution?

Comment: Is there a *problem* with that? Seems fine to me.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree with you, but maybe there is a better solution or even built-in way?

Comment: *"better"* how? And you actually want that _at runtime_, which isn't TypeScript's purview.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, ok, thank you :)

Comment: THere is no better way. Your solution is perfect )

Comment: AFAIK, TypeScript does not have any built in runtime functions. Only types

Comment: @captain-yossarian, I understood. Thank you, man!)